# Ansible, how to define a list in host inventory?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook and I want to define a list of strings in my hosts file.

Here's my host file:

```
[dashboard]
1.2.3.4 dashboard_domain=test site_domain=['one','two','foo', 'bar']
```

Here's my playbook that I attempted to write using the [list documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#flattening-a-list):

```
---
- hosts: dashboard
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes

  tasks:

    - name: ping
      ping:

    - debug: 
        msg: "Domain: {{dashboard_domain}}"

    - debug: 
        msg: "Site: {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{site_domain}}"
```

However running this playbook with `ansible-playbook -i hosts ping.yml` causes this error:

> TASK: [debug ] ****************************************************************
>   fatal: [1.2.3.4] => with_items expects a list or a set

This seems to be an issue of transferring the defined list from the host file to the playbook because defining the list directly in the playbook works:

```
---
- hosts: dashboard
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  vars:
    site_domain: ['one','two','foo', 'bar'] 
  tasks:

    #### APPLY HTTP-AUTH ####
    - name: ping
      ping:

    - debug: 
        msg: "Domain: {{dashboard_domain}}"

    - debug: 
        msg: "Site: {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{site_domain}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just quote the variable value:

```
[dashboard]
1.2.3.4 dashboard_domain=test site_domain="['one','two','foo', 'bar']"
```

It seems in case of INI-formatted inventory files, Ansible does not parse the variable value if it starts with an unquoted `[` and passes it as a string.

---

Regarding your example: I'm not sure why you're not getting an `expected key=value` error on reading the inventory file, if you really have a space inside.

Comment: This is so counter-intuitive I'd never have got it right. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

@techraf does answer your question and their solution is perfect if every host in the `dashboard` group has a `site_domain` list with different values.

Looking at your playbook, though, it seems that `site_domain` is constant across the whole `dashboard` group. If you had 10 hosts in `dashboard`, you would have to copy the list into each host's line. To avoid the repetition, you could have a `dashboard:vars` section in your inventory, where you can define variables that have the same value for all the hosts in the group:

```
[dashboard:vars]
site_domain="['one','two','foo', 'bar']"

[dashboard]
1.2.3.4 dashboard_domain=test
1.2.3.5 dashboard_domain=uat
1.2.3.6 dashboard_domain=integ
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#assigning-a-variable-to-many-machines-group-variables

If your inventory folder is more structured, you could also define variables for the `dashboard` group in a separate file, in YAML. Your inventory folder tree could be:

```
inventories
 |
 +-- group_vars
 |    \-- dashboard.yml
 |
 +-- hosts.ini
```

In that configuration, `dashboard.yml` could simply be:

```yaml
site_domain: ['one', 'two', 'foo', 'bar']
```

...or:

```yaml
site_domain:
  - one
  - two
  - foo
  - bar
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables