# How to loop through a list of variables set-up in an Ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Having an ansible inventory file like this:

```ini
hostname1 users=user1,user2,user3
hostname2 users=user1,user2
```

I need an Ansible playbook that will loop through each of the user variable list and run the `grep username /etc/passwd` command for each hostname/user variable

What I have so far is:

```yaml
---
- name: Grep shadow entries for users
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Get shadow entry for each user
      shell: "grep {{ item }} /etc/shadow"
      register: shadow_entry
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].users }}"

    - name: Print shadow entry
      debug:
        msg: "{{ shadow_entry.results }}"
```

But this does not loop through each user list but rather goes and runs `grep [user1,user2,user3] /etc/passwd`.

Also tried different variations on setting the inventory file like:

```ini
hostname1 users=["user1","user2","user3"]
hostname1 users='["user1","user2","user3"]'
hostname1 users="user1","user2","user3"
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are two different files. See [What is difference between `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445361/) and [What is the difference between `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461022/). "_Nothing seems to work_" is not a helpful problem description. Instead the output of each run or the output of `debug: var: ...` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

**How to loop through a list of variables set-up in an Ansible inventory file?**

For a file `cat hosts`

```ini
[test]
test.example.com USERS="['user1','user2','user3']"
```

an example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show users
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].USERS }}"

  - name: Show users
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ USERS }}"
```

will both result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show users] ***********************
ok: [test.example.com] => (item=user1) =>
  msg: user1
ok: [test.example.com] => (item=user2) =>
  msg: user2
ok: [test.example.com] => (item=user3) =>
  msg: user3
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How specify a list value as variable in Ansible inventory file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572092/)
- [Ansible: How to define a list in host inventory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149975/)

---

Please take note that it is recommended to proceed further with reading the account database fully via [`getent` module – A wrapper to the unix getent utility](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html).

> *Runs `getent` against one of it’s various databases and returns information into the host’s facts, in a `getent_` prefixed variable*

**See Q&A**

- [Ansible playbook to check user exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475117/6771046)

Comment: Why `{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].USERS }}` instead of simple `{{ USERS }}`?

Comment: Because I've just used the syntax from the initial question. But good point, I'll add the short and simple variable name to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Both options below are strings

```ini
hostname1 users=user1,user2,user3
hostname2 users=[user1,user2,user3]
```

You can test it

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: users|type_debug
```

gives in both cases

```yaml
  users|type_debug: str
```

See [Defining variables in INI format](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#defining-variables-in-ini-format)

- In the first case

```ini
hostname1 users=user1,user2,user3
```

*split* the items if you want to iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users.split(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [hostname1] => (item=user1) => 
  msg: user1
ok: [hostname1] => (item=user2) => 
  msg: user2
ok: [hostname1] => (item=user3) => 
  msg: user3
```

- In the second case

```ini
hostname2 users=[user1,user2,user3]
```

the string is a valid YAML list. Use the filter *from_yaml* to convert the string to the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
ok: [hostname2] => (item=user1) => 
  msg: user1
ok: [hostname2] => (item=user2) => 
  msg: user2
ok: [hostname2] => (item=user3) => 
  msg: user3
```

- You have to quote the string, either single or double if you put spaces into it

```ini
hostname2 users='[user1, user2, user3]'
```

---

- Use module [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#ansible-builtin-getent-module-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) to read */etc/shadow*. On the remote system, see `man getent` whether the database is available or not

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: shadow
```

This module will create a dictionary in the variable *ansible_facts.getent_shadow*. You can use it, instead of *grep*, to iterate *users*. For example, given the *users*

```ini
hostname2 users=operator,nobody
```

The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ ansible_facts.getent_shadow[item]|to_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ users.split(',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [hostname2] => (item=operator) => 
  msg: |-
    operator: ['*', '18397', '0', '99999', '7', '', '', '']
ok: [hostname2] => (item=nobody) => 
  msg: |-
    nobody: ['*', '18397', '0', '99999', '7', '', '', '']
```